# Determining Bases for Some Topology on $X$ (slight proof explanation)

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets is a basis for some topology $\tau$ on $X$ if and only if the following are true:
>
> 1. $X=\bigcup _{B\in \mathcal{B}}B$.
> 2. For every $B_{1},B_{2}\in \mathcal{B}$ and $x\in B_{1}\cap B_{2}$, there exists a $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subset B_{1}\cap B_{2}$.

I am trying to understand the proof for the other direction.

Assume $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies the first and second conditions. Let $\tau$ be all unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. I need to show that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\tau$.

To show that arbitrary unions are in $\tau$, let $\bigcup_{i\in I}B_{i}$, $\bigcup_{j\in J}B_{j}\in \tau$. Then $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_{i}\right)\cap \left(\bigcup_{j\in J}B_{j}\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I,j\in J}(B_{i}\cap B_{j})$. It says that from the second condition, $B_{i}\cap B_{j}\in \tau$. For some reason, I cannot seem to understand how this connection is made? Can someone explain for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $x\in B_i\cap B_j$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq B_i\cap B_j$. But then $B_i\cap B_j=\bigcup_{x\in B_i\cap B_j}B_x$. Clearly $B_i\cap B_j\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in B_i\cap B_j}B_x$, since each $x\in B_x\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in B_i\cap B_j}B_x$ for each $x\in B_i\cap B_j$, and on the other hand $\bigcup_{x\in B_i\cap B_j}B_x\subseteq B_i\cap B_j$, since each of the sets $B_x$ is a subset of $B_i\cap B_j$. Thus, $B_i\cap B_j=\bigcup_{x\in B_i\cap B_j}B_x\in\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

Define a topology on $X$ by declaring a subset $U$ of $X$ is open if and only if for each $x\in U$, there exists some $B\in \mathbb{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.

Let us first verify that this set, let us call it $\tau$, is indeed a topology on $X$.
Vacuously, $\varnothing\in \tau$. As we assume that each $B\in \mathbb{B}$ is a subset of $X$, $X\in \tau$.Let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$  be a collection of elements of $\tau$. We must verify that $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\in \tau$. To see this, let $x\in U_i$ for some $i$. As $U_i\in \tau$, there exists some $B\in \mathbb{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U_i\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$. Let $V_1, V_2$ be two members of $\tau$. We must show that $V_1\cap V_2\in \tau$. Let $x\in V_1\cap V_2$. By definition of $\tau$, there exists $B_1,B_2\in \mathbb{B}$, such that $x\in B_1\cap B_2\subseteq V_1\cap V_2$. Using 2. in the hypothesis, we deduce that $V_1\cap V_2\in \tau$. Clearly, $\mathbb{B}\subseteq \tau$. Hence each member of $\mathbb{B}$ is open. Moreover, it is easy to see that every open subset of $X$ is the union of members of $\mathbb{B}$. $\square$

Moreover, it is easy to verify that the topology for which $\mathbb{B}$ is a basis is unique.